# Parse color dialog results into brush

Tags: .net, winforms, f#

How do I parse the result from a color dialog so that I can set the color of a brush to its value?

This is what I have and what I want to do.

```
 let b = Brushes.Black
 btnColor.Click.Add(fun _ ->
 ColorDialog.ShowDialog() (* Here I want to set the selected color to my brush b *) |> ignore )
```

Comment: Is this Wpf or Winforms. Also which ColorDialog are you using?

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned it's windows forms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll take a guess that you're talking about `System.Windows.Forms` here.

```
open System.Drawing
open System.Windows.Forms

let getColorFromUser initialColor =
    use dlg = new ColorDialog(Color = initialColor)
    if dlg.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK then
        dlg.Color
    else
        initialColor

// example with mutation
let mutable b = new SolidBrush(Color.Black)

b <- new SolidBrush(getColorFromUser(Color.Black))
```

See the [Values docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233185.aspx) for more info on mutable.

Comment: Seems to be working but when I do this I don't notice any change to the brush b, any idea why? :/
btnColor2.Click.Add(fun _ -> b = new SolidBrush(getColorFromUser(b.Color)) |> ignore)

Comment: FSharp is mostly immutable by default, so you can't change the value of `b`. If you do want to update `b` then you should mark it as `mutable`. I'll add to the code example.

Comment: I keep forgetting that... thanks again! problem solved.